# Paramethers with '/' in ExpressJS

Tags: angularjs, node.js, express

I was wondering how to make a GET call passing a param that contains the '/' character. Is it possible?

Example: `GET /service/products/GIANAX W/22 cps`

Thank you all very much!

Comment: You need to escape the slash

Comment: [`encodeURIComponent`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent)

Comment: Thank you all very much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [encodeURIComponent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/encodeURIComponent) on the piece of the URL that contains the `/` and use the resulting string as your actual URL.

For example, if you call `encodeURIComponent()` on `"GIANAX W/22 cps"` and combine it back with the other part of the URL, you will get:

```
/service/products/GIANAX%20W%2F22%20cps
```

Note, you can only call encodeURIComponent on one path segment at a time.  You can't call it on the whole URL or otherwise it will escape the actual path separators that you want to retain.

Comment: Thank you very much. 
Sorry, but I didn't mention I'm using AngularJS in the frontend. I found how to use encodeURIComponent in that condition. Now using filter returning the output of the JS encodeURIComponent function.